# How to create an instance of a class with and without value

Tags: php, class

I have a class which I use to create a list of customers or a single customer.

I was simply calling new Customer() and then calling the method

```
customer->setCustomerList()
```

Then I decided to create a constructor and set an individual customer_id to return just one customer:

```
public function __construct($customer_id)
```

now my setCustomerList call throws an error because the `new Customer()` call is missing the customer_id...

I now get this error:

`Warning: Missing argument 1 for Suppliers::__construct()`

I know if I pass a value it will work but that's not my question - my question is how do I let the class create an instance without the customer_id?  Just an empty instance WHILE ALSO leaving the constructor to create an instance with a custoemr_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the declaration of your constructor so the parameter is optional, with a default value :

```
public function __construct($customer_id = null)
```

Then, inside your constructor :

- if `$customer_id !== null`, use that parameter, as a value has been passed.
- else, it has not been passed as a parameter -- and, so, don't try to use it.

The relevant section of the manual : [**Default argument values**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 1):

`public function __construct($customer_id = NULL)`

Gives a default value when none is passed.